# Setting up a unit testing environment in laravel 8

Tags: php, database, laravel, tdd, laravel-8

So I'm currently working on a larger web app using the laravel (v8) framework. Obviously I have a development environment and a production environment and soon even a staging environment. Since it's neccessary to test my classes (Models, Controllers, etc.) I have already written some unit tests. While doing that I encountered a problem: I really don't want to run my tests on the actual database (not even on the dev env) for various  reasons, to name the main two:

1. data integrity
2. when I use a separate in-memory database for my tests they will run way faster.

So my question is how can I set up my laravel application such that it uses a in memory database (sqlite) for running the unit tests and a regular mysql database for the regular app operations?

Answer (score 1):

### Setting up an in-memory SQLite database for Laravel tests

This is not well documented, as I'm increasingly finding with a lot of Laravel environment/infrastructure stuff, and this stuff is especially hard because between slow migration times, tests being ridiculous to debug and there being no easy way to seeing whether the in-memory database is actually being used, it's both a hard and slow process to figure out what's going wrong and where.

This is the set of steps I eventually confirmed to work after a day of trial and error.

1. Copy the contents of your `.env` file to create a file called `.env.testing`. Change the value of `APP_ENV` to `testing`, and remove all of the `DB_` entries.
2. Make sure your `phpunit.xml` has the following lines and uncomment them:

   ```
   <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="memory_testing"/>
   <end name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
   ```

   Or if using Laravel 8 and earlier:

   ```
   <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="memory_testing"/>
   <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
   ```
3. Add the following array to your `connections` in `database.php`:

   ```
   'connections' => [

      'memory_testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
      ],

      ...
   ```
4. Finally, run `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear the caches.

Your unit and feature tests should now be using the in-memory SQLite database, while your local should continue using the database configured in `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite for testing purposes. Simply add the following lines in your phpunit.xml file in the project root

```
<PHP>
    ...
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    ...
</php>
```

This will use your SQLite connection in your database.php file for the migrations and database operations when you are dealing with testing.

The normal application will tun using your MySQL DB connection.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me. Do you need to set the ENV_APP or something else besides this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
 
        //Load .env.testing environment
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
 
        $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
 
        return $app;
    }
}
```

Reference doc: https://www.phplab.info/categories/laravel/how-to-specify-a-separate-database-for-unit-testing-on-laravel-5